# Why my JS code is not showing any other slide while calling the JS function showSlides(SLIDEINDEX); even if I change the value of SLIDEINDEX?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't have an idea whats wrong with my js code, please check below and help me to show other secific slide just by changing the value of SLIDEINDEX

```
    // initialize slideindex with 0 as you want to show the first slide first
var SLIDEINDEX = 3;

showSlides(SLIDEINDEX);

// creating function for showing slides
function showSlides(index){
    // lets select all the slides and dots using querySelectorAll method
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    var dots = document.querySelectorAll(".dots-navigation");
    // if slide index value is greater than length of slides then jump to 1st slide
    if (index >= slides.length) {SLIDEINDEX = 0;}
    // if we want to jump at the last of the slide incase the user is at the first one
    if (index < 0) {SLIDEINDEX = slides.length - 1;}

    // before showing slides we must hide all the slides and remove active-dots class using for loop
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
        // hide slide elements
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
        // hide dots active-dot class
        dots[i].classList.remove("active-dot");
    }
    // show the slide we want and set the dot class active-dot
    slides[SLIDEINDEX].style.display = "block";
    dots[SLIDEINDEX].classList.add("active-dot");

};
```

here are the other part such as the HTML and CSS code, please follow link
HTML code link :- https://pastebin.com/nUcqnXnj and CSS code link :- https://pastebin.com/T2CZPNeh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think SLIDEINDEX var is miss used. You set it only if it's outside of slides limits.

```
...
// if slide index value is greater than length of slides then jump to 1st slide
if (index >= slides.length) {SLIDEINDEX = 0;}
// if we want to jump at the last of the slide incase the user is at the first one
else if (index < 0) {SLIDEINDEX = slides.length - 1;}
// else set SLIDEINDEX with new index
else {SLIDEINDEX = index;}
...
```

Comment: Sorry to say but I don't know why its not working again, I did change it still the image remain the same as it was earlier.

Comment: Do you have any error message in your browser console (F12)?

Comment: yeah I have, look here :- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Comment: But I'm just trying to hide all the slides and removing the class active-dot from dots dom object before showing a slide using showSlides() function.

Comment: Ye, I have found my mistake and resolved it successfully anyway Thanks Camille...